# How should I do back up of research in motion registration information (.zip) during code signing process of Blackberry?

Tags: zip, backup, code-signing, blackberry-10

I have already got `PBDT.csj and RDK.csj` files after code signing process with this (https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/codesigning.html) link.

But when I am trying to signing registration and configuration I need to do it with second option which is already marked in attached image, but there need to have `research in motion registration information (.zip)` file backed up.

So anyone please tell me how should I take back up of `research in motion registration information (.zip)` during code signing process of Blackberry?

Please refer attached image for more details.

Thanks in advance.

[image: signing registration and configuration]

Comment: If I remember correctly, once you register to get your certificates and use them first time, when you set them up in QNX you can do a back up of the certificates which will be saved as .zip file, apparently they have changed their site details, can't seem to find the tutorial page for back up. But you can still register using the two csj files (the first option in your image) and you can proceed in development.

Comment: yes nsawaya, I forgot to back up. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, There was option to take back up as a `Research in motion` after passing `PBDT and  RDK` files while choosing first option in attached image.

That I forgot to do it.

Which is very important to take back up if you want to register your `Blackberry devices` again with same signing keys.

Also refer this link http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Backup-and-Restore-BlackBerry-Code-Signing-Keys/ta-p/837925

Answer (score 1):

Go to **QNX Window >> Preferences >> Blackberry >> Signing**

[image]

Comment: This is process that we need to pass backed up (.zip) file here for restore configuration. but I was expecting only that how we can do back up (.zip) file in my local system folder which we are using here.

Comment: It will generat .zip file contain **author.p12**, **barsigner.csk**, **barsigner.db**